# Joist not sitting on brick wall

Tags: joists, brick

We are swapping out the current joist on our stairway for a bigger one 2x7 instead of 2x6 as we are making the head clearance more.

however, we’ve seen something a bit worrying. It appears that this joist is not sitting on the brick wall… and the whole dining room ceiling is being supported by one nail… please tell me I’m wrong?

That 127 Cove you see is where we chiselled some back plasterboard of the coving which is from the ceiling in the living room, as we didn't realise it was the living room at this point!

There's a 2 brick thick wall running under the stairs (I think they removed a brick and a half to cater for the stairs going under the wall), and the long joist going along the stairs is supporting perpendicular joists holding the dining room ceiling. We want to swap out this joist with a slightly higher joist as we are increasing staircase clearance height to 2m (was 1.5m) but the long joist doesn't seem to sit on the actual brick wall.. and we are a bit worried if this is ok and if we can continue tbh

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Update: More pictures which might help. **

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm really not sure what I'm looking at here. Perhaps some annotations of the images would help. What makes you think the joist _should_ rest on the brick wall? It looks like there's a sill of sorts embedded in a foundation wall.

Comment: Hey Isherwood. Did you see the rest of the other pictures? There's a lot of pictures to get an idea of what's happening, i'm not quite good at annotating pictures... Basically it looks like the dining room ceiling is floating on this side as i don't know what is supporting it. We want to swap out the 2x6 joist you see parallel to the stairs with a 2x7 but worried as it's not sitting on the brick wall to support the dining room ceiling.

Comment: It looks to me like the lower joist and the upper one (under the carpet) are both resting on a sill plate, which I assume rests on something more substantial than those bricks. Is that not the case?

Comment: When you say the lower joist are you talking about those 2 2x2s that are sitting together on top of that plasterboard? How can we check it's sitting on a sill plate? You can see the ceiling coving there but what the joists are sitting on is a mystery. Remove carpet?

Comment: Also, what are we expecting the sill plate to be resting on?

Comment: The lower joist has the squiggly caulk/glue bead and the steel straps on it. The upper one is perpendicular to it and parallel to the sill plate. I have no idea what your foundation might contain, but there has to be _something_ under that sill.

Comment: By sill you mean the 2 2x2s? They definitely seem to be sitting on plasterboard.... what else it could be sitting on i don't know as it's a thin layer and nothing much seems to be there.... The upper joist also is cut and stops where the stairs are so that isn't going anywhere either...

Comment: I'd love to know where the structural engineer expected you to be able to buy a 2X7.
As far as I know, there is no such standard size lumber. Is there a reason why you are not using 2-2x8 joists for this?

Comment: 2x7 is quite popular in the UK. He actually said 3x7 sistered would be better but that's way overkill imo

Comment: At this point I'm stepping out. I can't say much of anything with confidence through a tiny internet tube. Get someone local to have a look. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I reach the same conclusion that as @Isherwood,  if you are talking about the joist I pointed out in the picture, it is resting on a top plate/sill and does not need to be sitting on the brick wall.  That joist is not just being support by the one nail in the end.

I do not see how replacing the 2x6 with a 2x7 is going to increase  the clearance in the stairwell by a ½ meter.

Also the joist you are considering replacing is a header joist with all the ceiling joist hanging off of it.  It would be difficult to swap out the 2x6 with a 2x7 without a lot of temporary support for the ceiling joist.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I had a structural engineer come round and I haven't explained well but the opposite end will have a perpendicular joist, basically a T, which will allow an extended clearance and for us to remove the existing joists to allow for more headroom. 2x7s (2 of them) were recommended by the structural engineer to use.

Comment: Plus, what is supporting the 2x4 sill? It looks like it's just resting on plasterboard.... unless i'm wrong?

Comment: I'm taking off the right side of the wall to see what it may be covering so i can show what it might be showing

Comment: I just checked and the sill (2 2x2s together) along with a random small piece of wood as you can see in the photos is what that joist is sitting on... Those 2x2s go from one end to another of the walls perhaps... I can't be certain where they go to but they go pretty far. But surely you can't support a ceiling on one end with just 2 2x2s??

Comment: I added another just to show where it's sitting on

Comment: Your diagram matches my initial interpretation, but now I'm confused by what's apparently a pair of 2x2s on top of drywall. *shrug*

Comment: Hey @isherwood, I added 2 more pictures which might help. The 2x4 you labelled is 2 2x2s together. I meant that it looks like there's drywall or a thin layer beneath those 2x2s... I don't know if you saw the other picture with the lower joist (the one with the glue lines) cut out to sit on those 2x2s... that can't be safe since the dining room ceiling 2x6 joists are connected to that joist? The other end of that joist connects to a 2x6 that seems to be suspended/held up by the roof :\...